How to describe when a person is sitting beside you at the table at a very specific direction?
So, how do you describe it when a person is sitting like this: 
Is it called "on the next corner" or "next to me on the corner"?

Perhaps you could describe this person as next around the table sitting to my right and facing to my left.


catty-corner (adjective, adverbs) US informal
(also catty-cornered, kitty-corner(ed)
In a position that is diagonally opposite someone or something else
Our offices are next to the bank and catty-corner from McDonald's restaurant.
Cambridge


kitty-corner (adv. or adj.)
variants or less commonly catty-corner or catercorner or
kitty-cornered or catty-cornered or catercornered
In a diagonal or oblique position
The house stood kitty-corner across the square
M-W


catty-cornered (adv. and adj.)
Forms: Also catacornered, catercorner, catty-cornered, etc.
U.S. and dialect
Diagonally; diagonal.
[OED online]



Even though the ridiculously long dining-room table was set for the
entire Roman army, only two people were seated. Townie was at one end
of the table, with Missy sitting catty-corner to his right.
Cynthia Baxter; Crossing the Lion (2010)


Without even thinking about it, I pressed my eye to the peephole to
get a visual for my soundtrack. The president and Dr. Humphrey were
sitting catty-corner to each other at the dining table.
Kristin
Gore; Sammy's House (2007)


Diagonally or a synonym would be your best bet. Perpendicular is also a good choice. At right angle of one another.
"I sat the the end of the table with her just around the bend."
"She was at my 2 o'clock." kind of clumsy.
Maybe talk about how main's right toes could touch other's left toes. Possibly accidently hitting into one another.
If it is a bigger, squarer table, opposite sides of the same conner.

Definitely not diagonally: the diagonal of the table connects two of its corners, and none of the seats in this diagram is at a corner. Perpendicular does not distinguish the 'another person' in the diagram from the person sitting in the third, unmarked chair.

Diagonal can be in reference to the person in question. The chess piece Bishop moves diagonally but is almost never in the conner of the board. For perpendicular, you can just say, "the next seat perpendicular to mine," showing it is the closest seat at an angle.
